# Regex accepting wrong string

Tags: java, regex

I've made a regex, this is a part of it:

```
"[[+31|0]2[[0-9]{2}|0]+]+|"+    //+312** / +3120 / 02** / 020 ERROR: 0800?
```

As you can see the wanted output is for example +312 or +3120 or 02..
But my problem is that the regex is accepting 0800 and 0900 also. Which I don't want. I also don't have any clue why it's accepting it because there is a 2 in the regex.

The part I pasted is a small part of the regex which is wrong.
Can anyone help me fixing this part?

Edit:
This is my full regex

```
                "(([+31]+|[31]+|"+              //+31 / 31
            "[[+31|0]2[[0-9]{2}|0]+]+|"+    //+312** / +3120 / 02** / 020 ERROR: 0800?
            "[[+31|0]6]+"+                  //+316 / 06
            ")[-]?"+                        // - / ..
            "[0-9]{3,8})|"+                 //einde van nummer.
            "(112)";                        //112
```

It's accepting 0800-1234 which it should not. The second rule is approving it.

Comment: @RyanCarlson I got a program which tests my regex with different possibilities. But it should not accept the 0800 which it does right now.

Comment: Are you sure it's failing? http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5B%2B31%7C0%5D2%5B%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%7C0%5D%2B%5D%2B%7C&input=0800%0A0203%0A

Comment: @TimB I editted my question so you can see the full regex. It does accept it.

Comment: Can you explain what you *think* this is doing: `[+31|0]`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It will use +31 or 0, it must choose one of those 2. After that it goes to the next things in the regex.

Comment: @RyanCarlson I got a program which checks the regex, if the string is accepted the program says true. If it's not accepted it says false. Right now it's accepting the 0800-1234 which it should not.

Comment: That's what everyone already suspects you think, and it is wrong. The above is a *character class* consisting of these characters: `+`, `3`, `1`, `|`, and `0`. On its own, it matches *one such character*.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik How should I do it then?

Comment: Listen to what Mark is telling you below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using square brackets and parentheses interchangably.  They're different.  `[]` surround character classes.  `()` surround sub expressions.

Based on your regex, a first step to fixing would be:

```
((\+31|0)2([0-9]{2}|0)+)+
```

http://fiddle.re/44t12

Comment: I'm editing the OP right now. Then you can see the full regex because those brackets should be there.

Comment: @Marc: So you're saying `[[0-9]{2}|0]+` **is** supposed to match `{`, `}`, `|`, etc, and **isn't** supposed to mean "two 0-9 characters or a single 0, one or more times"? Because if not, you're using square brackets (character class) on the outside when you should be using parantheses.

Comment: Hmm... I don't really understand it, it's supposed to mean two 0-9 characters or a single, 0 one or multiple times. But I don't know how I am supposed to use the brackets then. Can you explain this?

Comment: @Marc, I don't think StackOverflow is a good venue for giving an introductory lesson in Regular Expressions.  But here are much better tutorials than I could write anyway: [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Put differently, `[+31]+|[31]+` is exactly equivalent to `[+31]+`. The character class `[+31]` matches a single character which can be a plus, a one, or a three.